# rails_admin ArgumentError when trying to edit or create a new entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I'm getting this error while trying to create a new or edit a Limitation (model below)

ArgumentError in Rails_admin/main#new

Showing /Users/deini/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rails_admin-0.4.9/app/views/rails_admin/main/_form_filtering_select.html.haml where line #11 raised:

wrong number of arguments (0 for 1+)

Extracted source (around line #11):  (selected_id = field.selected_id)

```
    selected_id = selected.send(field.associated_primary_key)
     selected_name = selected.send(field.associated_object_label_method)
   else
     selected_id = field.selected_id
     selected_name = field.formatted_value
   end
```

System.rb

```
class System < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attachments

  has_many :limitations
  has_many :companies, :through => :limitations

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachments
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :companies

  attr_accessible :conf_type, :version, :hardware_type, :name, :attachments_attributes, :company_ids, :companies_attributes

  rails_admin do
    list do
      exclude_fields :created_at, :updated_at
    end
  end

end
```

company.rb

```
  class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :distributor
  has_many :users, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :limitations
  has_many :systems, :through => :limitations

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :limitations

  attr_accessible :distributor_id, :name, :system_ids, :email, :limitations_attributes

  rails_admin do
    list do
      exclude_fields :custom_url, :created_at, :updated_at
    end

    edit do
      exclude_fields :custom_url, :users
    end
  end

end
```

limitation.rb

```
class Limitation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :system
  attr_accessible :company_id, :system_id, :version_limit
end
```

I haven't modify anything in my rails_admin, any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is the signature of the selected_id method?

Comment: I'm sorry but what do you mean by signature of the selected_id method, how can I get that?

Comment: The line 'selected_id = field.selected_id' sets a local variable to the value returned when invoking the method 'selected_id' on the object 'field.' The error says you don't have enough parameters {wrong number of arguments (0 for 1+)} so I wondered what arguments the selected_id method takes.

Answer (score 1):

Actually i too got the same error. But then when i changed the name **System** to some other name in my entire code including model,table name and all, my code starts to work fine. Try changing the name **System** with some other word.